# How to modify the multiple values in the JSON file using python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to modify my JSON file in which I need to replace the file_name with the base path
as structured below:

```
data = {"images": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "file_name": "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/1110.jpg",
        "height": 3024,
        "width": 4032
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "file_name": "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/1111.jpg",
        "height": 3024,
        "width": 4032
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "file_name": "Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/1112.jpg",
        "height": 3024,
        "width": 4032
    }
]}
```

Here is my code which I tried

```
data = json.load(open(".\example.json"))
```

First I have check the full file_name with below code

```
for img in data['images']:
    print(img["file_name"])
```

Below is the Output for this cell

```
Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/1110.jpg
Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/1110.jpg
Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/1110.jpg
```

Then I modified it to get the base path as below

```
for feature in data['images']:
    feature['file_name'] = os.path.basename(feature["file_name"])
    print(feature['file_name'])
```

This is the output:

```
1110.jpg
1111.jpg
1112.jpg
```

When I am trying to dump this into a JSON file but I am only getting one file_name.

```
data = {1110.jpg}
```

I would like to get the output as below. Please help me with your inputs

```
data = {"images": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "file_name": "1110.jpg",
        "height": 3024,
        "width": 4032
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "file_name": "1111.jpg",
        "height": 3024,
        "width": 4032
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "file_name": "1112.jpg",
        "height": 3024,
        "width": 4032
    }
]}
```

Comment: create a list and append all of the outputs there and then iterate throught the list and add items from it to the json file or do it directly. also could You provide a bit more code on how You dump those json files etc

Comment: Thank you for the quick response @Matiiss, Yes I missed the dump JSON file. Anyways the below answer has solved my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works as expected if you have resolved the variable name difference.

Further, I would also suggest to open the file using context manager `with` so that it gets closed automagically when the `with` block is exited.

```
import json, os
with open(".\example.json", 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for feature in data['images']:
    feature['file_name'] = os.path.basename(feature["file_name"])
    
print(data)
```

Output:

Data in `json` file:

```
{'images': [{'id': 1, 'file_name': 'Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/1110.jpg', 'height': 3024, 'width': 4032}, {'id': 2, 'file_name': 'Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/1111.jpg', 'height': 3024, 'width': 4032}, {'id': 3, 'file_name': 'Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/Folder4/1112.jpg', 'height': 3024, 'width': 4032}]}
```

Formatted data:

```
{'images': [{'id': 1, 'file_name': '1110.jpg', 'height': 3024, 'width': 4032}, {'id': 2, 'file_name': '1111.jpg', 'height': 3024, 'width': 4032}, {'id': 3, 'file_name': '1112.jpg', 'height': 3024, 'width': 4032}]}
```

Comment: Thank You @Krishna, it worked exactly as per my expectations. As you mentioned this was the variable name difference issue. I corrected it.

Comment: Glad that the problem was resolved quickly!

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in this line `for feature in temp['images']:`, please change it to `for feature in data['images']`

```py
for feature in data['images']:
    feature['file_name'] = os.path.basename(feature["file_name"])
print(data)
```

```json
[{'file_name': '1110.jpg', 'height': 3024, 'id': 1, 'width': 4032},
 {'file_name': '1111.jpg', 'height': 3024, 'id': 2, 'width': 4032},
 {'file_name': '1112.jpg', 'height': 3024, 'id': 3, 'width': 4032}]
```

Comment: Thank You @Sancith Jain.